# Surprising problem to access Wifi Hotspot in Android 4.4 (Rooted)

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, wifi-hotspot

I have uni proxy using NTLM authentication which I am sharing via hotspot created using this command

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="NAME" key="PASSWORD" keyUsage=persistent
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

While my Android 4.4 (rooted) is connecting immediately, I'm unable to browse. I have tried,

1. giving the proxy in Wifi/proxy settings.
2. giving localhost:8080 and 3128 in Wifi/proxy settings.
3. giving WiFi IP in Wifi/proxy settings.

Also, LAN has auto-IP and auto-DNS. Hotspot has fixed IP and DNS is empty.

I thought it will take a minute, but one hour later, I'm still stuck.  What am I missing here ?

Comment: If you're trying to have one device sharing a WiFi connection using a WiFi hotspot, it won't work. You need to either use USB tethering, bluetooth tethering or an Ethernet cord.

Comment: I have LAN connection with proxy which I'm sharing via laptop hotspot and trying to consume in Android phone. Since, this is a pretty common use case, I think it's supported..not sure what I am missing though.

Comment: You might want to look into something like [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en) to use proxy authentication in Android. It claims to support NTLM authentication.

Comment: I tried ProxyDroid. I can ping google from android terminal , but can't browse or chat.Not sure if the right place to ask,but  if my LAN proxy is A:portA, LAN gateway is  B:portB  and my hotspot IP is C:portC, which one should be given in ProxyDroid ?

Comment: The LAN proxy (A:portA)

Comment: Thanks ,I can ping google from android terminal, I have to fix apps and browser connection.